# Cómo solucionar error Argument 'path' has incorrect type (expected str, got NoneType)

Tags: python

necesito ayuda para extraer datos de marea (componente northward_velocity y eastward_velocity) desde el modelo FES2014 que ya tengo instalado... Para hacerlo tengo un código de ejemplo, pero me genera muchos errores y no sé que modificaciones hacer para obtener las componentes northward_velocity y eastward_velocity para zona o mis coordenadas, necesito saber que modificaciones debo hacer en el código o si es que me falta algún otro archivo para poder correrlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Este es el código de ejemplo:

```
import argparse
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fes


def usage():
    """
    Command syntax
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Program example using the Python API for FES.')
    parser.add_argument(
        'northward_velocity',
        help='Path to the configuration file that contains '
        'the defintion of grids to use to compute the '
        'northward velocity (V-component)',
        type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument(
        'eastward_velocity',
        help='Path to the configuration file that contains '
        'the defintion of grids to use to compute the '
        'eastward velocity (U-component)',
        type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument(
        '--date',
        help='Date of calculation of the velocities tide.',
        default=datetime.datetime.now(),
        type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    """
    Main program
    """
    args = usage()

    # Create handler
    eastward_velocity = fes.Handler("ocean", "memory",
                                      args.eastward_velocity.name)
    northward_velocity = fes.Handler("ocean", "memory",
                                       args.northward_velocity.name)

    # Creating a grid that will be used to interpolate the tide
    lats = np.arange(1.7, 2.7, 1.0)
    lons = np.arange(-79.34, -78.46, 2.0)

    assert lons.shape == lats.shape
    size = lats.size

    lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

    dates = np.empty(lons.shape, dtype='datetime64[us]')
    dates.fill(args.date)

    # Create handler
    u_tide, lp, _ = eastward_velocity.calculate(lats.ravel(), lons.ravel(),
                                                dates.ravel())
    v_tide, _, _ = northward_velocity.calculate(lats.ravel(), lons.ravel(),
                                                dates.ravel())

    # Creating an image to see the result in meters
    u_tide = u_tide.reshape((size, size))
    u_tide = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(u_tide), u_tide)
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.title("eastward velocity")
    plt.pcolormesh(u_tide)

    v_tide = v_tide.reshape((size, size))
    v_tide = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(v_tide), v_tide)
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.title("northward velocity")
    plt.pcolormesh(v_tide)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Este es uno de los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llamando a tu programa?

Comment: @SergioR Hola, se llama fes_uv

Comment: Y los argumentos también los incluyes? Esos que le indican donde buscar northward y eastward velocity?

Comment: @SergioR Si, pues pongo por ejemplo '--northward_velocity' y tengo las carpetas con esos datos en la misma ruta que el programa fes_uv.

Comment: Pregunto porque el error consiste en que donde espera leer una ruta para saber el directorio de los archivos no está recibiendo nada (NoneType). Por eso es importante saber como estás llamando al programa.

Comment: Entonces como debería estar? @SergioR

Comment: `python fes_uv.py ruta_northward/archivo_northward ruta_eastward/archivo_eastward`